# Can we use only year-month of timestamp column as distribution key in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've a table of around 300m records on Redshift.

Is there anyway we can specify year-month as **distribution key** instead of timestamp. Will it improve performance if I opt for **key diststyle** since mostly we need to query quarterly data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do **not** want to do this.

In Amazon Redshift, the **Distribution Key** (`DISTKEY`) is used to distribute data between slices (there are multiple slices per node). When a query joins two tables using the DISTKEY it runs much faster since data in both tables relating to that key are on the same slice -- there is no need to move data between slices and the slices can operate in parallel. The DISTKEY should be the field that you use most-often to **JOIN** tables together.

There is also a **Sort Key** (`SORTKEY`) that sorts data stored on a slice. A query that that uses this SORTKEY in a `WHERE` clause will work more efficiently because the query can skip-over blocks on the disk. Each 1MB disk block contains values relating to one column in one table. Each block has a **Zone Map** that identifies the minimum and maximum values in the block. If the block does not contain values that match the WHERE clause, then Redshift does not need to read the block. This makes the query extremely fast.

So, if you mostly query **quarterly data**, then you should set the table's **SORTKEY** to the timestamp field. This will allow every slice to process data in parallel, while skipping irrelevant disk blocks. **Do NOT use a date value for the DISTKEY** -- that would result in only one slice performing the query and it would run slower. Instead, set your DISTKEY to what you mostly use to join that table with other tables (eg customer ID).

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. Could you please make me understand how data is distributed over multiple nodes. And how Distribution Style can affect performance?

Comment: Documentation: [Choose the Best Distribution Style](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html) & [Distribution Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Distribution_examples.html). I also recommend watching the [Redshift presentation from AWS Summit](https://aws.amazon.com/summits/sydney/on-demand/), which gives a good visual analogy for data distribution.